# Got Error "Argument 3 missing or nil" in Roblox

Tags: roblox

I am coding in Roblox and I came across an error telling me that argument 3 is missing or nil. This is my code

```
local tweenservice = game:GetService("TweenService")
local part = workspace.TruckBlock

local Tween = tweenservice:Create(part,TweenInfo.new(1,Enum.EasingStyle.Linear,Enum.EasingDirection.Out,0,false,0,{Position = Vector3.new(5.642, 1.65, -17.99)}))
wait(5)
Tween:Play()
```

I am a new coder and I really don't understand what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that a function you have called expects three arguments, and you only provided two. [TweenService:Create()](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/TweenService/Create) expects a target, some tween info, and a dictionary of props to change.

Your code has all the right pieces, but you put a close parentheses in the wrong place :

```
e,0,{Position = Vector3.new(5.642, 1.65, -17.99)}))
   ^ the ) needs to go here                      ^ not here
```

This causes the dictionary of props to be passed into the tween info constructor instead. So instead of TweenService:Create() getting three arguments, it's only getting two.

It is hard to spot the error because you've put everything onto one line. Once you break things out into multiple lines, it is easier to read and your error messages will be easier to understand too.

```
local tweenservice = game:GetService("TweenService")
local part = workspace.TruckBlock

local tweenInfo = TweenInfo.new(1, -- time
    Enum.EasingStyle.Linear,       -- easing style
    Enum.EasingDirection.Out,      -- easing direction
    0,                             -- repeat count
    false,                         -- reverses
    5)                             -- delay

local props = {
    Position = Vector3.new(5.642, 1.65, -17.99),
}

local Tween = tweenservice:Create(part, tweenInfo, props)
Tween:Play()
```

Comment: What if I want to move a group of blocks that I have already grouped?

Comment: If your group of blocks has a PrimaryPart, you can use Model:MoveTo() https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Model/MoveTo